# window.matchMedia javascript returns wrong results on Chrome Version 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

To determine the mode of the viewport (landscape / portrait) I wanted to use `window.matchMedia` as per tips on a [blogpost](https://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change) by David Walsh (of Mozilla) along with a [polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) popularized by Paul Irish (of Google).

Caniuse says that the crossbrowser support for the [matchMedia api](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) is great!

So I tested the following code on Chrome Version 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit) on my mac:

```
const mql = window.matchMedia('(orientation: landscape)');

console.log('loadedThePage', mql.matches) 

mql.addListener(m => {
      console.log('resizeMePlease', mql.matches) 
});
```

And here's the output I got on dev console on page load:

```
loadedThePage false
resizeMePlease true
```

LOL. I didn't even resize the browser (chrome) and it returned a result. That's one thing and the other being that on first load `mql.matches` returns a wrong answer: `false`.

Since Chrome is a major browser I think it's a no-go to be able to use matchMedia api unless someone has figured out a work around for this. And that's exactly my question: Has anyone else come across and solved this issue?

I'm aware about the [issues](http://pioul.fr/cross-device-cross-browser-portrait-landscape-detection) of `window.orientation` api so I cannot use that either.

Comment: `54.0.2840.99` on windows works fine ... so it seems to be a Chrum on Mac problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out this happens only when using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) module bundler to load the application. Using a simple script tag in the head of the page instead fixed it for me.

Also, I got rid of webpack completely.